# Angular 5 gets undefined value of @Input() variables into the functions calling from ngOnInit()

Tags: typescript, angular5

Here is the code sample of the child component.

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
    ...,
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataArray: Array<any>;

    constructor(...) {
        ...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
    }

    getData(){
        console.log(this.dataArray);
    }
}
```

I am creating the dataArray into parent component and passing it into child using the selector and input property. Below is the sample how I am passing the dataArray from parent to child.

```
<example [dataArray]="dataArray"></example>
```

I need to made calculations on the dataArray when the component is initializing and show the data into view. Currently, it never gets the data into getData().

Comment: Please, give more detail. How are you using that component? How are you setting teh `dataArray` input property?

Comment: I am creating the dataArray into parent component and passing it into child using selector and input property. I.e. <example [dataArray]="dataArray"></example>

Comment: When do you create the array?

Comment: @abetteroliver The array is created by the data gathering from API.

Comment: That means it is most likely not availavable when `ngOnInit` is invoked. The optimum solution depends on your application's design, but using `ngOnChanges` as suggested by the answer below is certainly a feasible option.

Comment: @abetteroliver yes, the issue is exactly the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not set dataArray properly or eventually later than you expect. Please try to find out if it is set anyway by using OnChanges() additionally. If you really set it properly but too late for OnInit(), you should have an Output from OnChanges().

```
import { ..., OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
    ...,
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() dataArray: any;

    constructor(...) {
        ...
    }

    ngOnInit() { }

    getData(){
        console.log('ngOnInit()', this.dataArray);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        // please note: changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
        console.log('ngOnChanges()', this.dataArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of posting a second answer with the same content as before. People even voted for your other one.